# I need to make countdown pause if the user not active in this tab and contune if active

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    {
        literal
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
    (new Countdown({
                seconds: {
                    /literal}{$current_permission['permissions_link_waiting_time_sec']}{literal},onUpdateStatus:function(a){$("#wait_button").text({/literal
                }
                "{$lang_35}... " {
                    literal
                } + a)
        }, onCounterEnd: function() {
            $("#wait_button").remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "api.php",
                data: "suffix=" + $("#suffix").val(),
                dataType: "json",
                error: function(b) {
                    var msg = JSON.parse(b.responseText).msg;
                    alert(msg);
                },
                success: function(a) {
                    a = a.long_url;
                    $("#button-bar").html('<a id="skip_button" href="' + a + '" role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-skip navbar-btn fixed-height-btn">{/literal}{$lang_36}{literal} &#187; </a>')
                }
            })
        }
    })).start()
    });

    function Countdown(a) {
        function d() {
            e(b);
            0 === b && (f(), g.stop());
            b--
        }
        var c, g = this,
            b = a.seconds,
            e = a.onUpdateStatus || function() {},
            f = a.onCounterEnd || function() {};
        this.start = function() {
            clearInterval(c);
            c = 0;
            b = a.seconds;
            c = setInterval(d, 1E3)
        };
        this.stop = function() {
            clearInterval(c)
        }
    }; {
        /literal}
</script>
```

Comment: There are syntax problems with your code that you should probably fix first.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the blur/focus events. Here's a simple example:

```js
var countdown = new Countdown(/* insert code */);
countdown.start();

window.onblur = function() {
   countdown.stop();
}

window.onfocus = function() {
 countdown.start();
}
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Can I see your code? The code that you posted isn't valid Javascript; it may have gotten messed up when you tried to post it.

Comment: Here's a version I put together real quick that works: https://output.jsbin.com/bazubujevo

Comment: the edited code not working i dont know why they edited it :( i hope you using the original code that i posted it in justpaste

Comment: The original code depends on PHP/Smarty code that I don't have access to. I made minor modifications to the JS, and removed the PHP so it would run in jsbin. I hope that you can modify your code based on my code; you can't just copy and paste.

Comment: If your modified code doesn't work, I can take a look at it and try to find the problem.

Comment: can you message me on skype  username = iqtoon